# VS 2013 cannot create new asp.net web application project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So I'm trying to create a new asp.net web application in Visual Studio 2013. I select the empty project template (have also tried Web Forms too) click Ok.

Then I get an error message "Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).

I have search the net for help but no joy yet. I have seen lots of people saying that in Tools > options > Source Control > Environment to make sure "Get Everything when a solution or project is opened" is unticked. By default all these boxes are unticked. In the Source Control Environment Seetings it has Team Foundation with nothing ticked beneath. Not sure what to do?

Comment: It may or may not be relevant, but on the chance that it may could you please add to the question which Operating System you are using?

Comment: Same error code, same VS, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848925/visual-studio-2013-new-project-unspecified-error-exception-from-hresult-0x

Comment: hi @StephenKennedy. I'm using Windows 7. I'm just looking through the link you sent, cheers. The answer to that link though doesn't appear to fix my issue. Just checking the other answers

Comment: Did any of those answers sort it for you mate?

Comment: no sadly. May try reinstalling Visual Studio