# Visual Studio 2013 -> New Project -> ASP.Net MVC App -> Unspecified error e_fail

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Well, I think I have banged my head a lot to get the answer on this issue, hence raising this again.
Some people might get answer here [Visual Studio 2013 > New project > unspecified error (exception from hresult: 0x80004005 (e_fail))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848925/visual-studio-2013-new-project-unspecified-error-exception-from-hresult-0x)

I have Windows 7 Pros SP1, 64bit proc.
I installed VS 2013 Prof.
Clicked New project and started with New MVC 4 Internet facing application.

Thats it. End of the story. Somehow VS dont buzz forward and just gives unspecified error (exception from hresult: 0x80004005 (e_fail))

I tried cleaning \Documents\IISExpress\config folder, resetting IIS Express, reinstalling VS, reinstalling IIS Express and nothing helps. Dont know why VS wants to add IIS Express to new solution, but can experts help me to get started with VS 2013..?

Comment: You could try installing the latest update http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48129

Comment: sorry, latest update didnt helped. But the error message is different this time.
Configuring IIS Express  failed with the following error: Filename : \\****\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
Error : Cannot write configuration file

Comment: I gave full Read Write access to everyone for this folder \Documents\IISExpress\config\  but still error is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was quite simple. We need to disable the default encryption of Documents\IISExpress folder from property window.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to start another project type 
Is not easy to know what's not working good but, in my opinion is the VS. Uninstall the VS and install another time. Download the last version of VS from Microsoft website.

Comment: Hi.. thx for reply. tried reinstalling, but didnt worked. Esko suggested update, and is giving new error after that.

Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error: Filename : \****\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config Error : Cannot write configuration file

Comment: I gave full Read Write access to everyone for this folder \Documents\IISExpress\config\  but still error is coming