# Installing template for VS 2015 enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, kmdf, wdf

I have VS 2015, and I also have Windows Driver Kit 10.0 But in VS 2015 Enterprise, I could not find any template to write KMDF related development. I tried to install so search for template for KMDF or WDF but I could not find it. How can I install KMDF template in VS 2015 enterprise edition? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy. I had to install WDK after installing VS 2015, I did that and it worked fine. problem solved.